# Django inline forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have to models, an Article and a Photo. There is a many2many relation between them. I need to design an Admin form that works better for editing them.

I batch upload photos and the Photo models are created. Then when I write the articles, I want to be able to edit the Photo models as an inline form.

When I set it up as described so far, I get an article edit form, with a selector to click on the name of each photo. I would like to have all unassigned photos shown, with a text box for the cutline on each photo and checkbox. When I put a checkbox and save the article the pictures are associated with that article. I also need to save the updated Photo objects with the text under each photo.

Suggestions for how I should go about this?

Models.py

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    cutline = models.CharField("Cutline", max_length = 1012, null = True)
    uploadDate = models.DateField()
    imagefile = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path, max_length=250, 

class Articles(models.Model):
    pictures = models.ManyToManyField(Photo, related_name='article', blank=True)
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length = 255)
    story = models.TextField("Article")
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms  
from django.forms import BaseInlineFormSet
from django.forms.formsets import BaseFormSet
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.db.models import Count, Q
from News.models import Articles, Photo

# Create the form class.
class PhotoIForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Photo
         fields = ['cutline', 'imagefile']

class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Articles
         fields = ('title', 'story')


class BasePhotoFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BasePhotoFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.queryset = Photo.objects.annotate(articles_count=Count('article')).filter(articles_count=0)
    print(a)
```

Views.py

```
@login_required
def article_edit(request):
    # Create the formset, specifying the form and formset we want to use.
    #PhotoFormSet = modelformset_factory(Photo, formset=BasePhotoFormSet, fields = ('cutline', 'imagefile')) #This doesn't work - seems to fail with the m2m fk
    PhotoFormSet = modelformset_factory(Photo, fields = ('cutline', 'imagefile')) # close but it doesn't allow me to set up the initial items and limit photos to ones without assigned articles


article = Articles.objects.get(pk = 2718)


if request.method == 'POST':
    article_form = ArticleForm(request.POST, article=article)
    photo_formset = PhotoFormSet(request.POST)

    if article_form.is_valid() and photo_formset.is_valid():
        # Save user info
        print("Data is valid save"

else:
    article_form = ArticleForm(instance=article)
    photo_formset = PhotoFormSet()

context = {
    'article_form': article_form,
    'photo_formset': article_formset,
}

return render(request, 'News/articleInline.html', context)
```

Comment: you should provide some code because SO is not a resource where you define functionality and other developers code it for you.

Comment: if you add your code sample, I can probably help you.